# List.Remove from one is also removing from another

Tags: c#, winforms, list, foreach

My method runs the following:

```
public void FrmClosed_Action(string name)
       {
           foreach (string item in this.origList)
           {
               if (item == name)
               { this.itemList.Remove(item); }
           }
           if (this.itemList.Count == 0)
           { Application.Exit(); }
       }
```

When I run the code `itemList = 2` and `origList = 2`. When an `item` is found matching the `name`, `itemList` is rightly reduced to `1` but the strange thing is so is `origList`. This happens straight away, as soon as the `foreach` enters the second run it crashes saying `collection was modified; enumeration operation may not compute`.

Comment: Did you do `itemList = origList` or vice versa somewhere along the way?

Comment: You cannot remove items from a list in a foreach loop. That's why you are getting "collection was modified; enumeration operation may not compute." error.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll Note that the OP is attempting to loop over one list and remove from a 2nd.  Chances are (as per my first comment) that both variables are pointing at the same actual list though.

Comment: If the purpose of `itemList` is just to allow you to do a `foreach` and remove from `origList` you could instead do a `for` loop starting at the end of `origList` and you can remove without an error.

Comment: @juharr Or just call `.Remove` without any loops and if statements... it's rather unclear as to what use this code would actually be...

Comment: @JamesThorpe Actually `RemoveAll(item = > item == name)` as it should remove all occurrences.

Comment: @juharr Yes that's true.  Either way - probably no need for the loop or copy of the list :)

Answer (score 10):

It looks like `origList` and `itemList` refer to the same instance of `List<string>`. Make sure that `itemList` is actually a distinct copy of `origList`, i.e. don't do `itemList = origList`, because it just copies the reference to the same list. Instead, you can do `itemList = new List<string>(origList)`, which creates an independent copy.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, I was doing as you thought.
I'll test it out and get back to you.